# Adding additional string to an existing value in a HTML form's input box before submission

Tags: html, forms, post, input, save

I have a form with an input box and I want to change the value before submit.

Example:

```
<form action="savefiends.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="123456"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I save the value as `123456@example.com` without editing `savefiends.php`?

P.S. user can edit the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onsubmit` attribute as shown in the snippet below.

**Note:** I added extra checking to avoid appending `"@example.com"` if already present. Also I replaced the action attribute content by `"#"` to avoid form submission.

```js
function resetId(){
  var idInput = document.getElementById("id");
  var suffix="@example.com";
  // just to check if @example.com is already present
  var checkRegExp=new RegExp(suffix + "$"); 
  if (!idInput.value.match(checkRegExp)) idInput.value +="@example.com";
  alert("Value before submit:" + idInput.value);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="resetId();return false">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="123456" id="id"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```